# Stop-AzureVM: No deployment found in service

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I want to stop and de-allocate a Windows VM in Azure.

In PowerShell, I use the command:

```
Stop-AzureVM - ServiceName [servicename] - Name [machinename] - Force
```

However, I get the following error message in PowerShell:

> WARNING: "No deployment found in service [servicename]

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

**Troubleshooting steps:**

1. Is the VM already in Shutdown or Deallocated state.
2. Do you have more than one subscriptions. If yes then select correct subscription using below cmdlet and then try to stop the VM:

   ```
   Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName "<<Your SubscriptionName here>>"
   ```

   or

   ```
   Select-AzureSubscription -Id "<<Your Subscription ID>>"
   ```
3. If you have only one Azure Subscription then check if you created the VM using ASM i.e. old portal (https://manage.windowsazure.com) or ARM i.e. new portal (https://portal.azure.com). If you used new portal then you need to use ARM related PowerShell cmdlets like below:

   ```
   Stop-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName "resource group name" -Name "VM name"
   ```

Reference for ARM PowerShell cmdlets: [Azure Resource Manager and PowerShell](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-ps-manage/)

Comment: 1. The VM is not in shutdown or deallocated state. 2. I have used first option, command succeeded but no visible feedback. 3. I have created it in New portal. 3. When entering the command: Stop-AzureRmVm - ResourceGroupName , I get the following feedback: Run Login-AzureRmAccount to login.

Comment: Update: I have entered Login-AzureRmAccount, then I need to login , and after entering login credentials, I enter Stop-AzureRmVM - ResourceGroupName "name" - Name "name", and then the VM shuts down and gets deallocated. How can I prevent to first need to login before I can execute the Stop-AzureRmVM command?

Comment: I believe you don't want the popup for the login and want it to happen non-interactively and fully automated way. You can use below code:

        $secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString “YourPass” -AsPlainText -Force

        $mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential (“YourUser”, $secpasswd)

        Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $mycreds

You will need to login using Org account instead of live id. Refer: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=331007&clcid=0x409